# How to turn off annoying jump of screen when CKEditor focus

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a problem in Opera browser: when I'm trying to set cursor in a place below last existed element - browser jumps somewhere to the bottom. In other browsers - it scrolls to the cursor.

How to overcome it? or turn of that jumps at all?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using the latest CKEditor 3.6.5? I can't reproduce this issue.

BTW. You should report this issue on https://dev.ckeditor.com/. Then we'll be able to investigate this case.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, we have 3.6.2. But I've fixed this issue (if I could call it so) via setting editor body `min-height` to 90%. (not 100% - cuz we will see overflow-y scroll.